# Kendo re-bind dropdownlist datasource

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, kendo-ui

I have a section of HTML that contains a rather large set of input controls that is generated dynamically from a set of JSON data returned from the server.

The HTML controls are built from the JSON data along with the items associated with them.

The drop-down list selection items are bound using the attributes:

`data-bind='source: sourceObject'`
`data-text-field='optionText'`
`data-value-field='optionValue'`

This is the javascript that creates the input select control:

```
function CreateSelectList(label, i, name) {
    var element = '<select data-bind=\'source:reportFormData.FormField[' + i + '].Options.Option\' data-value-field=\'optionValue\' data-text-field=\'optionText\' id=\'' + name + '\' name=\'' + name + '\' data-role=\'dropdownlist\'></select>';
    return CreateFormField(label, element);
}
```

**Problem: I need to selectively modify the data source of one of the dropdowns. I can't figure out how to programmatically change the datasource.**

This doesn't work:

```
var ddlData = $("#ddl_location").data("kendoDropDownList");
ddlData.setDataSource(jsonData.Option);
```

nor does this:

```
$("#ddl_location").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "optionText",
    dataValueField: "optionValue",
    dataSource: jsonData.Option
});
```

I've also tried calling these after:

```
ddlData.trigger("change");
ddlData.refresh();
```

`jsonData.Option` is in equivalent format to the original JSON element `Report.FormField[i].Options.Option` e.g. `"Option": [ {"optionText": "All", "optionValue": "0"}, ...`
The difference here is that it is a new subset of data that needs to replace the original data source.

here is an excerpt from the full JSON used to initially create the controls:

```
{
"Report": {
    "report_id": "1",
    "FormField": [{
        "description": "End DateTime Picker",
        "name": "end_date",
        "label": "End Date",
        "FieldType": "datepicker",
        "displayOrder": "2",
        "isRequired": "1",
        "requiredFieldValidationMessage": "End Date is required."
    },
    {
        "description": "Client",
        "name": "ddl_client",
        "label": "Client",
        "FieldType": "dropdownlist",
        "displayOrder": "3",
        "isRequired": "0",
        "Options": {
            "Option": [{
                "optionText": "All",
                "optionValue": "0"
            },
            {
                "optionText": "*Airport Business Center",
                "optionValue": "68955"
            },
            {
                "optionText": "*Cushman & Wakefield",
                "optionValue": "68996"
            },
            {
                "optionText": "*IBMC College ",
                "optionValue": "68804"
            }
            ...
    }
```

Comment: Looks like `FormField[i].Options` may not always be available. Are you trying to set multiple DropDownLists with multiple lists?

Comment: @SunnyPatel `i` refers to input control number `i` , it could be a dropdown list, date picker, textfield, etc. It will only have a `.Options` element if it is of type `dropdownlist` This works correctly, the form is generated fine. I need to modify a single dropdownlist datasource AFTER the form has already been generated. Does that make sense?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the data into a DataSource object to see if it makes a difference? `$("#ddl_location").data("kendoDropDownList").setDataSource(new kendo.data.DataSource({data: jsonData.Option}))`. You can also manually trigger the datasource update by calling `ddlData.trigger("databound");`.

Comment: `new kendo.data.DataSource(jsonData.Option)` does the same thing as `n‌​ew kendo.data.DataSource({data: jsonData.Option})`.

Comment: @SunnyPatel This appears to be the right direction. It finally changes the dropdownlist (it clears it to be empty, instead of re-populating it), however I am now getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: e.slice is not a function` that is coming from the kendo library file `kendo.all.min.js:11` Do you have any idea what is going on now?

Comment: Without seeing a better stack trace, all I can suggest is for you to use your Browser's debugger, and pause on uncaught exceptions, and see what the value of `e` is. Trace that back up and see if a data type is not being initialized.

Answer (score 1):

use read() on dataSource:

```
var ddlData = $("#ddl_location").data("kendoDropDownList");
ddlData.setDataSource(jsonData.Option);
ddlData.dataSource.read();
```